# Where is the Parity v2.5.11 web UI at?

Tags: parity

This used to open the parity web UI for my local node, but now the browser it says it cannot connect, as if I just entered any other bogus port:

http://127.0.0.1:8180/

I upgraded from Parity 1.7 to 2.5. Has the web UI port changed?

Accessing http//127.0.0.1:8545 and :8546 (RPC ports) has an effect (the node responds with a single line of text with further instructions in both cases).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UI Support for Parity was deprecated a while back. ( see https://github.com/paritytech/parity-ethereum/issues/8969).

As an alternative, you can use fether (https://github.com/paritytech/fether)